# Google Public Patent Data SQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-public-datasets

I am trying to retrieve specific cpc codes AND assignees via SQL in the Google public patent data. I am trying to search for the term "VOLKSWAGEN" and cpc.code "H01M8".

But I got the error:

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY
> <STRUCT<name STRING, country_code STRING>>, STRING. Supported
> signature: ANY = ANY at [15:3]

code:

```
SELECT
  publication_number application_number,
  family_id,
  publication_date,
  filing_date,
  priority_date,
  priority_claim,
  ipc,
  cpc.code,
  inventor,
  assignee_harmonized,
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications`
WHERE
  assignee_harmonized = "VOLKSWAGEN" AND cpc.code = "H01M8"
LIMIT
  1000
```

I'm also interested in searching multiple assignees such as:

`in ("VOLKSWAGEN", "PORSCHE", "AUDI", "SCANIA", "SKODA", "MAZDA", "TOYOTA", "HONDA", "BOSCH", "KYOCERA", "PANASONIC", "TOTO", "NISSAN", "LG FUEL CELL SYSTEMS", "SONY", "HYUNDAI", "SUZUKI", "PLUG POWER", "SFC ENERGY", "BALLARD", "KIA MOTORS", "SIEMENS", "KAWASAKI", "BAYERISCHE MOTORENWERKE", "HYDROGENICS", "POWERCELL SWEDEN", "ELRINGKLINGER", "PROTON MOTOR")`

I have recently started to work with SQL and do not see the mistake :/

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: In ANSI SQL you need to use `'` for strings, some databases use the `"` for case sensitive column names.

Comment: `"` works fine in Google BigQuery. Both `'` and `"` are case sensittive.

Answer (score 0):

In Google BigQuery `UNNEST` is needed to access ARRAY elements. This is described here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

The following query works for me.

```sql
SELECT
  publication_number application_number,
  family_id,
  publication_date,
  filing_date,
  priority_date,
  priority_claim,
  ipc,
  cpc__u.code,
  inventor,
  assignee_harmonized,
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
  UNNEST(assignee_harmonized) AS assignee_harmonized__u,
  UNNEST(cpc) AS cpc__u
WHERE
  assignee_harmonized__u.name = "VOLKSWAGEN AG"
  AND cpc__u.code LIKE "H01M8%"
LIMIT
  1000
```

The following are changes I made to generate results:

1. `UNNEST(assignee_harmonized) as assignee_harmonized__u` to access `assignee_harmonized__u.name`.
2. `UNNEST(cpc) as cpc__u` to access `cpc__u.code`.
3. `assignee_harmonized__u.name = "VOLKSWAGEN AG"` as `"VOLKSWAGEN"` returns no results.
4. `cpc__u.code LIKE "H01M8%"` as `"H01M8"` returns no results. An example value is `H01M8/10`.

This returns the following:

> Query complete (2.3 sec elapsed, 29.2 GB processed)

If you want to screen multiple assignee names, `IN` will work like the following, however, you need to have an exact match like `VOLKSWAGEN AG` or `AUDI AG`.

`assignee_harmonized__u.name IN ("VOLKSWAGEN", "PORSCHE", "AUDI", "SCANIA", "SKODA", "MAZDA", "TOYOTA", "HONDA", "BOSCH", "KYOCERA", "PANASONIC", "TOTO", "NISSAN", "LG FUEL CELL SYSTEMS", "SONY", "HYUNDAI", "SUZUKI", "PLUG POWER", "SFC ENERGY", "BALLARD", "KIA MOTORS", "SIEMENS", "KAWASAKI", "BAYERISCHE MOTORENWERKE", "HYDROGENICS", "POWERCELL SWEDEN", "ELRINGKLINGER", "PROTON MOTOR")`

If you want to do a `LIKE` style match with multiple strings, you can try `REGEXP_CONTAINS`:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains

Comment: Many thanks, now I created this code to screen multiple companies. 
Is it possible to get the query of requests out of "cpc__u.code" in one row cell each? with a ", " to seperate the codes between the output string?.
Same I like to consider for the assignee_harmonized__u.name here as well !

Do you think the companies will be screened with this precedure and the "IN" operator? in the following comment..

Comment: `IN` will work but you need to have exact string matches which you do not have in your example, e.g. `VOLKSWAGEN AG` vs. `VOLKSWAGEN`. I updated the answer to cover this.

Comment: I'm not sure whata you mean by "Is it possible to get the query of requests out of `cpc__u.code` in one row cell each? with a ", " to separate the codes between the output string?" Can you provide an example output you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, now I created this code to screen multiple companies.
Is it possible to get the query of requests out of "cpc__u.code" in one row cell each? with a ", " to seperate the codes between the output string?.
Same I like to consider for the assignee_harmonized__u.name here as well !

Do you think the companies will be screened with this precedure and the "IN" operator?

```
SELECT
  publication_number application_number,
  family_id,
  publication_date,
  filing_date,
  priority_date,
  priority_claim,
  cpc__u.code,
  inventor,
  assignee_harmonized,
  assignee
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
  UNNEST(assignee_harmonized) AS assignee_harmonized__u,
  UNNEST(cpc) AS cpc__u
WHERE
  assignee_harmonized__u.name in ("VOLKSWAGEN", "PORSCHE", "AUDI", "SCANIA", "SKODA", "MAZDA", "TOYOTA", "HONDA", "BOSCH", "KYOCERA", "PANASONIC", "TOTO", "NISSAN", "LG FUEL CELL SYSTEMS", "SONY", "HYUNDAI", "SUZUKI", "PLUG POWER", "SFC ENERGY", "BALLARD", "KIA MOTORS", "SIEMENS", "KAWASAKI", "BAYERISCHE MOTORENWERKE", "HYDROGENICS", "POWERCELL SWEDEN", "ELRINGKLINGER", "PROTON MOTOR")
  AND cpc__u.code LIKE "H01M8%"
LIMIT
  100000
```